# Spring: link between WebApplicationContext and ApplicationContext?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, applicationcontext

I am working on a Spring application. I started from creating a small java app using spring. Later, it became necessary to add a web interface. I decided to use Spring MVC. Now I am confused. In my web.xml I have

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

where mvc-dispacher-servlet.xml contains beans necessary for web logic while applicationContext.xml contains beans performing some specific operations. My question is: Are beans in these files going to be aware of each other? Is it going to be a one big container which includes beans from both config files? or these containers are separate?

Comment: You can always try and see.

Comment: (However it is going to be one context, it's not really a common use case to have multiple contexts in an app.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will be in one context which will be loaded from the web application context. Its the same as you would do when using the application context and passing in multiple files to it.